# SEO for react-native and react-native-web application, can it work?

Tags: seo, javascript, react-js, seo-software

I am looking at the generated HTML in my `react-native-web` web application and the volume of HTML is huge.

The whole application is build with `<div />` and there are some `role` attribute such as  `role="navigation"` in many places.

- This is what makes me ask, can SEO today solve the problem to have good indexation in Google for `react-native` web application?
- If not, how can I improve the components of a native application in order to have a normal SEO potential? (Example: wrapping the react-native components in `<nav/>`, `<header />` and increasing the `Platform.OS === 'web'` and `.web.js` custom code)

I was not able to find any resource about that matter, resources that talk about it would be much appreciated.

Comment: To me, you are touching on a whole issue I have with React and similar frameworks/libraries/etc. Some have lost touch with the fundamentals as these things have created their own version of HTML and CSS. Many no longer understand how basic elements and their properties work. They can no longer edit them to do what they want and rely on other people's code--and Stack Overflow--to fix their problems.

Comment: @Rob when using React Native Web, they automatically assign, and now removed all attributes that you passed in a Native Component. The Native Web is very useful to get one App for Native and for Web, and you can't do nothing on their properties, since you put them in Native Component, and they are removed when transformed to Web. For example, for me, they keep `arial-label` attribute, but removed `role`, or any `data-id` or `dataId`, but why? When using direct React, i control everything well. They can add those friendly SEO features to keep the package reliable.